# jQuery: how to avoid transparent effect on a mask div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use jQuery to popup a div layer when click attach pic button, in the div there is an embeded div which concludes fileupload control letting user choose file from there computer. I set the css of the mask div

```
opacity=0.70
```

which works fine, but I found that the embeded div also got transparent effect. Even I set the inner div opacity=1.0, it still feels like it is in opcity=0.70. How to avoid the transparent effect on inner div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to pull the inner div out and just lay it over the top of the transparent div.

Comment: Agreed. If positioning is a problem, use jQuery's `.offset().left` and `offset().top` to get the offset of one div and assign it to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could use alpha channel on the parents background.

This will set the background of the parent div to be black with 70% opacity.

```
.parentDiv {
    backround:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

The child div will have it's own styles too

```
.childDiv {
    background:red;
}
```

So you will have a slightly transparent parent with fully opaque child

Also note that you can set the border colors the same way if you need semitransparent or transparent borders

Also note that you can use the filter function too (I think IE has a special one.

```
filter:alpha(opacity=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".test").click(function()
                    {
                        $("body").append("<div id=\"transparentDiv\"></div>");
                        $("#transparentDiv").css({opacity:0.7, backgroundColor:"#000", position:"absolute", width:"100%", height:"100%", top:0, zIndex: 4});
                        $("body").append("<div id=\"scalableDiv\"><p>Hello!</p></div>");
                        $("#scalableDiv").css({"width":"10px","height":"10px","backgroundColor":"white","left":"auto","zIndex":"5", opacity:1.0, position: "absolute"});
                        $("#scalableDiv").animate({width:"200px",height:"200px"},"normal","linear");
                    });
            });
```

BTW, I've started with jQUery 2 days ago, I don't know if this is a proper solution either